# hydra experiment override order

Tags: python, fb-hydra

hydra experiment sample:

```
# @package _global_
defaults:  
  - override /segment: segment_RGB

look_up_region : 20
```

below hydra config which in `experiment` mode will pass final value of `look_up_region` equal to 10:

```
defaults:
  - segment: segment_CMYK
    
look_up_region : 10
```

and below hydra config which in `experiment` mode will pass final value of `look_up_region` equal to 20:

```
defaults:
  - segment: segment_CMYK
    
look_up_region : ???
```

really i need the 10 with original config and i need the 20 only with experiment
but i am forced to use `???`

how can i solve this?

one more thing, the framework is very awesome,never been happier with so many parameter which we are manage them by hydra.

**Update**:

Ok, found the answer by starting everything from scratch:

removing the colorlog plugin from main config:

```
- override hydra/job_logging: colorlog
- override hydra/hydra_logging: colorlog
```

why this do conflict?
can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the kind words, glad to hear Hydra is helping!

Could you provide a minimal repro example on what the issue is here? The code snippets do not have enough info, and I can only guess what is going on here. (it might be easier to do so on our github repo, but it's up to you :) )

In any case, this seems like a question on the composition ordering,  you can check out our doc here https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list

Comment: ok ,i opened a page in github : [to github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1706)